# Copying files from SD to external hard drive - keeps saying the folder no longer exists but allows me to copy one at a time

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sd-card

So this is a very peculiar problem...

I have a 16GB SD card that has RAW photos of it from my Canon DSLR camera.  I also have an IOGear SD-to-USB converter.  I am trying to copy the photos off of the SD card onto a Seagate external hard drive, but any time I try to copy more than one file, it tells me that the directory no longer exists and fails.  I can move over one photo at a time, but only if I do it really slowly (i.e. give it 4-5 seconds between copy operations), and even then sometimes it fails with the same error.

It is very strange and I have never had this error before.  I should note that recently my computer told me that I had to reformat the SD card for some reason... it was all old photos so I didn't really care and just did it, using the system defaults.  Could that maybe have caused the issue?

Other notes: Windows 8.1, I can provide other details if requested...

Comment: You may have a failing sd-card

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're running into a glitch with the USB bus where either the SD card or the external hard drive is dropping out in the middle of the file transfer.  This can happen if the two drives are pulling too much power over the USB ports, or they're flooding the bus with too much data all at once.

The dropouts could have corrupted the data on the SD card and that's why you saw the error. Or @Davidostill could be right and your SD card is failing.  Try running CHKDSK on it.

Also see if you can make it work by making sure that the devices are attached to different USB root hubs.  The best way to ensure that is to plug the SD card reader into a USB port on the front of the computer, and the hard drive to a port on the back, making sure nothing else is plugged into the ports directly above or below it. If this is a laptop, try plugging them in on opposite sides (one on the left and one on the right).

The USB spec says each port should have 5V, 500mA (USB2) or 900mA (USB3) of power going to it, but some ports just aren't in spec.  This is usually the case with front-mounted USB ports, as they run a cable to a header on the motherboard whereas the back ports are soldered directly onto it.  If your external hard drive is bus powered (i.e. doesn't plug into the wall), it's pretty much a guarantee that it's hogging all the juice.